# F# solution to "Escape from Zurg" puzzle

Tags: f#

I have written an F# program to solve the "[Escape from Zurg](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/papers/Zurg_JFP04.pdf)" puzzle

My code is the following. but somehow something is wrong with the way I am returning the boolean value when the puzzle is solved.

On the line

```
retVal = Move (cost + (MoveCost toy1 toy2)) Right remainingElements
```

I get a warning

The expression should have type 'unit' but has type 'bool'. If assigning a property use the syntax 'obj.Prop <- expr'

and I see that even though the function returns true when the puzzle is soved. when it returns the retVal remains false.

Below is my code.

```
open System

type Direction = 
    | Left
    | Right

type Toy = {Name: string; Cost: int}

let toys = [
                {Name="Buzz"; Cost=5}; 
                {Name="Woody"; Cost=10}; 
                {Name="Rex"; Cost=20}; 
                {Name="Hamm"; Cost=25};
           ]

let MoveCost toy1 toy2 =
    if (toy1.Cost > toy2.Cost) then
        toy1.Cost
    else
        toy2.Cost

let rec Move cost direction group = 
    match group with
    | [] -> if (cost > 60) then
                false
            else 
                Console.WriteLine("Solution Found!")
                true
    | _ ->
        match direction with
        | Left ->
            let retVal = false
            let combinations = Set.ofSeq (seq {for i in group do for j in group do if i <> j then if i < j then yield i, j else yield j, i})
            for pair in combinations do
                let (toy1, toy2) = pair                
                let remainingElements = List.filter (fun t-> t.Name <> toy1.Name && t.Name <> toy2.Name) group                
                retVal = Move (cost + (MoveCost toy1 toy2)) Right remainingElements
                if (retVal) then
                    Console.WriteLine ("Move " + toy1.Name + " and " + toy2.Name + " with the total cost of " + cost.ToString())
            retVal
        | Right ->
            let retVal = false
            let toysOnRightBank = List.filter (fun t-> not(List.exists (fun g-> g = t) group)) toys
            for toy in toysOnRightBank do
                let cost = cost + toy.Cost
                let retVal = Move cost Left (toy :: group)
                if (retVal) then
                    Console.WriteLine("Move " + toy.Name + " back with the cost of " + toy.Cost.ToString())
            retVal

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    let x = Move 0 Left toys
    0
```

Comment: Note that your `MoveCost` implementation could be more succinctly and efficiently implemented as `let inline MoveCost { Cost = cost1 } { Cost = cost2 } = max cost1 cost2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cann't reassign a `let` binding. It should be:

```
let mutable retVal = false
```

...

```
retVal <- Move (cost + (MoveCost toy1 toy2)) Right remainingElements
```

However, you could easily rewrite it so that `mutable` isn't needed:

```
let res =
  [
    for i in group do 
      for j in group do 
        if i < j then yield i, j elif i > j then yield j, i
  ]
  |> List.filter (fun (toy1, toy2) ->
    let remainingElements = List.filter (fun t-> t.Name <> toy1.Name && t.Name <> toy2.Name) group                
    Move (cost + (MoveCost toy1 toy2)) Right remainingElements)

match res with
| [] -> false
| _ ->
  res |> List.iter (fun (toy1, toy2) ->
    Console.WriteLine ("Move " + toy1.Name + " and " + toy2.Name + " with the total cost of " + cost.ToString()))
  true
```

EDIT: I posted a [complete solution on gist](https://gist.github.com/3132740), if you need a reference implementation.